# Intellij Idea does not recognize ivy.xsd

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd

Why my IDE does not recognize xsd by URI ?

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the schema first. IntelliJ allows to do that using intentions. Set cursor on the red marked fragment, press Alt+Enter and select 'Fetch External Resource'. Schema should be downloaded and you will start getting element suggestions in the file.

Sometimes automatic resource fetching may not work and the location will remain red marked. In such case you will need to download the schema to some location to disk and select 'Manually Setup External Resource' from intentions menu. Point to the downloaded file and you should get it working.